# Update jQuery 1.8.3 to jQuery 1.9.0 in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

we use ASP.NET MVC 4 and i update our project to use jQuery 1.9.0 from jQuery 1.8.3,
BUT now Not work client scripts,like jQuery validation,jquery unobtrusive ajax and 3rd party jQuery library and etc!

According to http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released we must use [jQuery Migrate Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate).we use Bundling in our MVC project,but when i use this plugin, jQuery.migrateWarnings not available in console!

My Question:

how we must update jQuery 1.8.3 to jQuery 1.9.0 without any problem in ASP.NET MVC 4 with Bundling enabled?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Zaki problem is solved when i updated other dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

Run your application and from your browser view the application's source - is the version of jQuery 1.9.0 or 1.8.3?

In Visual Studio, if you go to Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution... then on the left click updates and you should see jQuery listed - click update.

As far as I know, this will look after everything. Check the source again.

One other thing you can do: go to Solution Explorer -> App_Start -> BundleConfig.cs - make sure the first `bundles.Add` call is like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js", 
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"));
```

EDIT:

Read [this.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)

Look at new bundle code - obviously be sure you have downloaded the migrate file.

Comment: please read my question,i can update jquery.

i said:

"BUT now Not work client scripts,like jQuery validation,jquery unobtrusive ajax and 3rd party jQuery library and etc"

Answer (score 1):

You should using Nuget to update.
Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages Solution (stop debug mode if you in there)

```
- when update jquery, you need update other js lib also like 
 + Jquery Validate
 + Microsoft Jquery Unobtrusive Validate
 + Other lib if you think it relate..
```

and in _layout.cshtml
Make sure you have something like

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

if you use ajax validate and jqueryui...

Answer (score 1):

Just open the package manager console in the `nuget` package manager 
and run the command:

```
Install-package jQuery
```