# Error with jquery references and getting two versions of jquery at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, websocket

For some reason I am getting version 1.8.2 of jQuery added to my solution even though there is no reference to it anywhere. Only 1.9.1 in the scripts. The code to add it is:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Things seem to work fine. I also have these errors in the console. Any ideas?

```
Exception was thrown at line 5288, column 6 in http://xxx:7000/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4224, column 4 in http://xxx:7000/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4242, column 4 in http://xxx:7000/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 5288, column 6 in http://xxx:7000/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4224, column 4 in http://xxx:7000/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4242, column 4 in http://xxx:7000/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
```

Comment: "even though there is no reference to it anywhere" There is somewhere, but where???

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412221/update-jquery-1-8-3-to-jquery-1-9-0-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: a migration tool is needed to move to a new version of jquery?  I thought that is what nugget was there fore.. update the jquery version in nugget and done ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look to the following code in the code bellow

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

take all of the versions of the jquery in you folder and put it in the page or view where you call it e.g in Layout page so you have to delete one of the jquery file , e.g jquery-1.8.2.js or jquery-1.9.1.js from the scripts folder of your project
it think it should work for you

Comment: No ref to 1.8.2 was in Scripts dir... but anyways I just forced the bundle to use 2.0.0 and it seems fine now... still no idea how that old version was being referenced..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you publish, you change your settings to remove all files at destination...